# Wordpress prepare-function needs that isset?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

In the genius function "prepare" of wpdb-class (in *includes/wp-dp.php*) I can't explain myself why `isset( $args[0] )` is necessary.

Alread clear is that `1 < func_num_args()` then the first entry is shifted. It remains `0 < func_num_args()` thus a first entry must exist. `$args[0]` could be `NULL` but if so, it cannot be an array, which is tested in the same "if" `if ( isset( $args[0] ) && is_array($args[0]) )`.

So what did I missed?

```
function prepare( $query, $args = null ) {
    if ( is_null( $query ) )
        return;

    if ( func_num_args() < 2 )
        _doing_it_wrong( 'wpdb::prepare', 'wpdb::prepare() requires at least two arguments.', '3.5' );

    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift( $args );
    // If args were passed as an array (as in vsprintf), move them up
    if ( isset( $args[0] ) && is_array($args[0]) )
        $args = $args[0];
    $query = str_replace( "'%s'", '%s', $query ); // in case someone mistakenly already singlequoted it
    $query = str_replace( '"%s"', '%s', $query ); // doublequote unquoting
    $query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%f|' , '%F', $query ); // Force floats to be locale unaware
    $query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%s|', "'%s'", $query ); // quote the strings, avoiding escaped strings like %%s
    array_walk( $args, array( $this, 'escape_by_ref' ) );
    return @vsprintf( $query, $args );
}
```

Comment: WordPress' code isn't the best to analyse for "why do this" because it's full of code which isn't required or is just bad. Don't get me wrong, WordPress as a tool is great - but the code isn't. The whole `func_get_args()` approach is sloppy and unnecessary - like a lot of WordPress core code.

Comment: Which approach do you prefer to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I don't know on which version you get this code, but on last WP version there isn't the `func_num_args` check - maybe you got this code from a transient version [when they made this fix](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/). In WP 4.3.1 the `prepare` function looks like that:

```
public function prepare( $query, $args ) {
    if ( is_null( $query ) )
        return;

    // This is not meant to be foolproof -- but it will catch obviously incorrect usage.
    if ( strpos( $query, '%' ) === false ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( 'wpdb::prepare', sprintf( __( 'The query argument of %s must have a placeholder.' ), 'wpdb::prepare()' ), '3.9' );
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift( $args );
    // If args were passed as an array (as in vsprintf), move them up
    if ( isset( $args[0] ) && is_array($args[0]) )
        $args = $args[0];
    $query = str_replace( "'%s'", '%s', $query ); // in case someone mistakenly already singlequoted it
    $query = str_replace( '"%s"', '%s', $query ); // doublequote unquoting
    $query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%f|' , '%F', $query ); // Force floats to be locale unaware
    $query = preg_replace( '|(?<!%)%s|', "'%s'", $query ); // quote the strings, avoiding escaped strings like %%s
    array_walk( $args, array( $this, 'escape_by_ref' ) );
    return @vsprintf( $query, $args );
}
```

So let's first translate the code:

```
if ( strpos( $query, '%' ) === false )
```

If a query without any parameter has been passed the custom error handler will tell user that he shouldn't use `prepare` for that kind of query.

```
$args = func_get_args();
```

Pretty straightforward, it get all the parameters sent to the function. It will get an array with that kind of structure:

```
Array(2) (
  [0] => $query,
  [1] => $args
)
```

Then right after:

```
array_shift( $args );
```

That will remove the first value of `$args` (`$query`), so we'll end up with a new array looking like that:

```
Array(2) (
  [0] => $args
)
```

Then the test that buzzing you:

```
if ( isset( $args[0] ) && is_array($args[0]) )
```

To understand why the `isset` is necessary, let's imagine you try to call the `prepare` function like that:

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE arg1 = %s");
```

So what's the result of that call? The query have a `%s` inside so it'll be consider valid. We'll get an argument table with the query only, after it will be shifted, we'll get an empty array. Then, `isset` will return `false` as the `0` index doesn't exist, **and** if `in_array` would be executed it'll display the following error (if notice errors display is enabled):

```
Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in ***.php on line **
```

Here is a little script illustrating this :

```
function test_args($arg1, $arg2) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    echo '<b>func_get_args : </b>';
    var_dump($args);
    array_shift($args);
    echo '<b>array_shift : </b>';
    var_dump($args);
    echo '<b>isset($args[0]) : </b>';
    var_dump(isset($args[0]));
    echo '<b>is_array($args[0]) : </b>';
    var_dump(is_array($args[0]));
    echo '----<br />';
}
test_args('arg 1');
```

Which will output the following:

```php
func_get_args : array(1) {
 [0]=>
 string(5) "arg 1"
}
array_shift : array(0) {
}
isset($args[0]) : bool(false)
is_array($args[0]) :
```

Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in E:\www\test-args.php on line 17

This is **why** this `isset` check is valid. **Though**, as `$args` is no longer optional we get a warning too for the prepare function, as we send only one parameter - something probably get lost in the dev process here. We miss the optional `$args` and the `func_num_args` check - those two as they were before would have been made the `isset` check useless and prevent any error to display. This may should be reported on [the WP bug report](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/).

Comment: I see. Then the `isset` is just to avoid the `Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in E:\www\test-args.php on line …`.

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for.